# Fgallery save image to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, image

Hi Sorry for being a noob but I'm learning. I have Fgallery working in my app but now I want to connect a bar button to an action to save the image to the phone. I need some code that gives me the current image (in the large image view) I hope someone can help me out with this. This is what I have:

```
- (void)handleEditCaptionButtonTouch:(id)sender {
// here we could implement some code to change the caption for a stored image
[networkGallery saveImageAtIndex:[networkGallery currentIndex]];
```

}

And here I have an image hard-coded but I need the current image:

```
- (void)saveImageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
if(image != nil){
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}   
return; 

}


//saveImage method
-(void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo{
[BT_debugger showIt:self:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"finished saving image: %@", @""]];
NSString *message;  
NSString *title;  
if (!error) {  
    title = NSLocalizedString(@"SaveSuccessTitle", @"");  
    message = NSLocalizedString(@"SaveSuccessMessage", @"");  
} else {  
    title = NSLocalizedString(@"SaveFailedTitle", @"");  
    message = [error description];  
}  
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title  
                                                message:message  
                                               delegate:nil  
                                      cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ButtonOK", @"")  
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];  
[alert show];  
[alert release]; 
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance
DK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else is looking for an answer. Here it is:

```
FGalleryPhoto *photo = [_photoLoaders objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index]];
UIImage *saveImage = [photo fullsize];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
 img.image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding and trying to help. What should I do in saveImageAtIndex to be able to save the current image to the phone? UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]; should be altered to something like tis: UIImage *image = the_current_image; but of course the_current_image should be something else and I cannot figure out what it should be. Hope you can help me out and thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Sam. I whish I would be that simple. But it doesn't know the CurrentImage and that's what I need to find out: what is (the code for) the current image..... Really appreciate this Sam! for your information: The code with the hard-coded image works perfectly

Comment: Updated answer, maybe this is what you want

Comment: Hi Sam, sorry for the delay, but this isn't what I'm looking for. Do you know FGallery? I have another script (not Fgallery) where the save to device option is working. The button tap is calling for this    UIImage *image = [self imageAtIndex:currentPageIndex];
   if(image != nil){
       UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil); and now I need the same solution for Fgallery but struggeling for days now to find the answer. Hope this explains better...

Answer (score 0):

In code above, in the *stringWithFormat* method, replace **index** with **_currentIndex**

FGalleryPhoto *photo = [_photoLoaders objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _currentIndex]];
UIImage *saveImage = [photo fullsize];